# menu changes position or overlaps beside active menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I think its better look at the URL so that you'll know exactly what I mean here.
http://ymm.valse.com.my/

When you click on any of the menu,the menu beside the active tab overlaps.Why is it so? I suspect it's the width. I put width:auto; same problem.I even tried fixing the width like width:150px; to no avail. How to solve this plz.

**I'm using Superfish .**

CSS

```
/* Main */
.sf-menu {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;  
    background-color: #2D2D2D;
    /*border-bottom:6px solid #393939;*/
    z-index: 90;
    /*background-image: linear-gradient(#444, #111);*/


   /*border-radius: 50px;*/
   /* box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;*/


}

.sf-menu li {
    float: left;
    /*padding: 10px 0;*/
    margin: 0 0 0 2px;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 1px  0 #222222, 
                2px  0 #383838;
    border-bottom:6px solid #393939;
     z-index: 100;
}
.sf-menu li a{
   display:block; padding: 10px 25px; height: 40px;color:#DDDDDD;
}
 .sf-menu a.active{margin-top:-5px; height: 51px; padding-top: 15px; position: absolute; z-index: 100;background-color:#072438; }
 .sf-menu li a
.sf-menu a {
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0 25px;
    color: #DDDDDD;
   /* text-transform: uppercase;*/
    font: bold 12px/25px Arial, Helvetica;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}


.sf-menu li:hover > a {
    color: #fafafa;
}

*html .sf-menu li a:hover { /* IE6 */
    color: #fafafa;
}

.sf-menu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
.sf-menu li:last-child{
    box-shadow: none;
}


/* Sub-menu */
.sf-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99999;    
    background-color: #2D2D2D;   
    border-bottom:none;
   /* background-image: linear-gradient(#444, #111);   */ 
    /*-moz-border-radius: 5px;*/
    /*border-radius: 5px;*/

}

.sf-menu ul li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;  
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #222222,
                0 2px 0 #383838;
    border-bottom:none;
}


.sf-menu ul a {    
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
    text-transform: none;
}
.sf-menu ul a:hover{
  margin-left:10px;
}
*html .sf-menu ul a { /* IE6 */   
    height: 10px;
    /*width: 150px;*/
    width:auto;

}


*:first-child+html .sf-menu ul a { /* IE7 */    
    height: 10px;
    /*width:150px*/
   width: auto;


}
/* active  menu*/


        /*end */
.sf-menu ul a:hover {
    /*background-color: #0186ba;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#04acec, #0186ba);*/

}

.sf-menu ul li:first-child a {
    /*border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;*/

}



.sf-menu ul li:first-child a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: -8px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #072438;

}

.sf-menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
    border-bottom-color: #072438; 

}

.sf-menu  li:last-child a {
    /*border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;*/

}

/* Clear floated elements */
.sf-menu:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}


* html .sf-menu             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .sf-menu { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```

HTML

```
<!-- Main Navigation Menu -->
<ul class="sf-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $data['config']['SITE_DIR']; ?>/">
                    <img src='<?php echo $data['config']['THEME_DIR']."/img/home_1.png"; ?>' onmouseover='this.src="<?php echo $data['config']['THEME_DIR']."/img/home_2.png"; ?>"' onmouseout="this.src='<?php echo $data['config']['THEME_DIR']."/img/home_1.png"; ?>'"></a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $data['config']['SITE_DIR']; ?>/main/page/about-us">About Us &#9660;</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $data['config']['SITE_DIR']; ?>/main/page/the-centre-point-of-any-web-projects">Centre-Point of Web Projects</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
            <!--<?php #echo $data['config']['SITE_DIR']; ?>/member/branch/index">-->
            <a href="#">Branches &#9660;</a>
        <?php Core::getHook('block-branches'); ?>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $data['config']['SITE_DIR']; ?>/main/news">News</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $data['config']['SITE_DIR']; ?>/main/event">Events</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $data['config']['SITE_DIR']; ?>/contact">Contact Us</a>
    </li>

</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

script if needed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var path = window.location.pathname.split('/');
path = path[path.length-1];
if (path !== undefined) {
  $("ul.sf-menu")
    .find("a[href$='" + path + "']") // gets all links that match the href
    .parents('li')  // gets all list items that are ancestors of the link
    .children('a')  // walks down one level from all selected li's
    .addClass('active');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because of the `position: absolute` on the class `.active` that is being added the `a`s inside the `li`:

```
.sf-menu a.active {
  margin-top: -5px;
  height: 51px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #072438;
}
```

Absolute positioning breaks the element out of the flow of the document thus your menu treats it like it's not even there. You should remove that.

[image]

**Update**
For that I would either add another class to the parent `li` and set `border-bottom: 0`. or you could add the `.active` class to the `li` instead of the `a` and change the `a` whose parent has a class of `.active`. Ex:

```
.sf-menu li.active{
  border-bottom: 0
}

.sf-menu li.active a {
  margin-top: -5px;
  height: 51px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #072438;
}
```

Comment: no prblm..thanks a lot...So first is .u see grey color border-bottom on active menu tab? I dont want it.I mean i dont want it to appear on active menu. I used z-index but doesnt work